# Create user profile page using Bloc, RxDart and Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, bloc, rxdart

My goal is to create an edit profile page in Flutter using the bloc pattern.

I've searched for a better/cleaner way to create a user profile page in Flutter using Bloc, but I can't find anything.

Right now I have to list every field out. Here's an example of 2 fields:

```
final _firstNameController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
final _lastNameController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

Function(String) get firstNameChanged => _firstNameController.sink.add;
Function(String) get lastNameChanged => _lastNameController.sink.add;

Stream<String> get firstNameStream => _firstNameController.stream;
Stream<String> get lastNameStream => _lastNameController.stream;

String get firstName => _firstNameController.value;
String get lastName => _lastNameController.value;


@override
  void dispose() {
_firstNameController?.close();
_lastNameController?.close();
}
```

There are a lot more fields and I don't want to have all this code if I can avoid it.

I'd prefer to only have 1 user bloc and update the specific field of that user.  I've added the following to a user bloc.

```
final _userFetcher = BehaviorSubject<User>();

Observable<User> get userStream => _userFetcher.stream;
User get user => _userFetcher.value;
Function(User) get changeUser => _userFetcher.sink.add;

@override
  void dispose() async {
    await _userFetcher.drain();
    _userFetcher.close();
  }
```

Here's an example of my user model:

```
class User {

  final Name name;

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = Name.fromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "first": name.first,
    "last": name.last,
  };
}
```

The issue is I can't figure out how to use a textfield to edit the "fist name" and "last name" fields in my "User" model.

Is this possible, am I going about this the wrong way, or should I stick to listing every field out individually?

Comment: I use a streambuilder on the "editProfile page" to listen: 

Widget buildProfile() {
    _loadUser();
    return StreamBuilder<User>(
      stream: _bloc.userStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return _buildErrorWidget(snapshot.error);

        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return _buildUserWidget(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          return _buildLoadingWidget();
        }
      },
    );
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help!

I ended up being able to edit the nested first and last name fields in my user model I listed above by implementing the following in my textField:

```
onChanged:(text) {
        User thisUser = _bloc.user;
        thisUser.name.last = text;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

To individually manage all those streams for each individual fields can be cumbersome. I would recommend you to try out this library [flutter bloc](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/packages/flutter_bloc) . It is a really good one that handles the state management pretty well. You just need to define the states and events and then for each event you can generate a state.

So for example you want to validate password field as the user is typing. You define an Event(eg. PasswordChanged). This will call a method in the bloc. In which you can write your business logic to check the validation.

After your validation logic you can yield a new State(error, succcess). This will cause your UI to be rebuilt and then you can update your UI according to your state.

You should checkout the documentation of this library. It also has some very good examples there.

Comment: Thank you Nick. I am using bloc, but I couldn't figure out how to change the value of a nested field. I was able to change it by creating a new user variable and editing its field. It then goes back to the _userFetcher in my user bloc.